# "No such file" while trying to download file with backslash and space in filename with Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

Trying to create local server. When downloading to client files without whitespaces such as `abc.txt`, `hello-world.png` everything works. But there is a problem with downloading files like `hello\ world.txt`. Program throws

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file

Simplified example of my code:

```py
# generating paramiko connection
t = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
t.connect(username=user, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)

remote_path = "/home/user/file.txt"
local_path = "/home/localuser/file.txt"
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path) # completing with no errors

remote_path = "/home/user/second\ file.txt"
local_path = "/home/localuser/second\ file.txt"
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path) # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the file is actually called `second file.txt`, not `second\ file.txt`. You might be confused because in shell one way to escape the space in the file name is using the backslash (though imo more common is to quote the filename). In Paramiko, you do not need to escape the filename (you cannot actually).

Comment: Bro you're right. I just removed all backslashes and everything works good!